# Magento redirect loop on cloud9

Tags: magento2, redirect

I try to install magento 2.0.1 on cloud9 (c9.io) but keep getting a redirect loop when calling the admin site.

http://mage2-lptt.c9users.io/admin_1a798x/
same with https.

The Log only shows:

> [Thu Jan 28 09:24:14 2016] 10.240.0.174:33786 [302]: /admin_1a798x/
>   [Thu Jan 28 09:24:15 2016] 10.240.0.188:41942 [302]:
>   /admin_1a798x/admin/index/index/key/1e30bc5f51f9e34b0a6234eaef2e20b03618a98c119c8ca17875e3977b929de2/
>   [Thu Jan 28 09:24:15 2016] 10.240.0.177:57048 [302]:
>   /admin_1a798x/admin/index/index/key/1e30bc5f51f9e34b0a6234eaef2e20b03618a98c119c8ca17875e3977b929de2/

...

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: what kind of server do you have? apache or nginx?

Answer (score 2):

If running Apache add these lines to .htaccess

SetEnvIf HTTPS On HTTPS=on

SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on

Comment: I confirm this is fixing the issue on Magento 1.

Answer (score 1):

The fix is very easy, you just need to **add the port to your base url**.

In your specific case you have to set it to:
http://mage2-lptt.c9users.io:80/

This won't affect browsing the website, as it's an issue related to port forwarding on Cloud 9. The Apache instance on your container will receive a request with the port in it even if the browser is not aware of that.

If you want to dig deeper, you can verify that the redirect loop is caused by a condition on line 44 of *Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Auth\Login*.

Comment: This works for Magento 2. Had to set the port to 443 for the secure base url too.